# Unable to use Postgres DB in docker-compose - ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I have a Node.js app and have set up docker-compose. I'm trying to use Postgres DB in the container.

Here is docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - redis
      - db
  angular: # image of nginx
    image: "qp-angular-nginx"
    ports:
      - "4200:80" # specify port forewarding

  redis:
    image: "redis:3"
    ports:
     - "6379:6379"     
  db:
    image: "postgres:9.6"
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
         - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data         
  dbadmin:
    image: "myimage/phppgadmin"
    ports:
         - "8085:80"
    environment:
        POSTGRES_HOST: db
        POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
volumes: 
     pgdata:
```

I have the containers running successfully and even database connected, but I get this error when making a DB request

```
 "stack": {
        "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
        "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",
        "syscall": "connect",
        "address": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 5432
    }
```

Comment: It might be worth trying a helper like `wait-for-it` or similar to ensure the DB is available before trying to connect: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect to the database from another docker container, use the service name in the connection string(`db` in your case). From the error message it seems that there is something wrong with your configuration. It tries to connect to localhost (`127.0.0.1`)

Comment: I've set host as `db` which is the name of the service in my docker-compose file

Answer (score 0):

For those, you use more recent structure project with a config file like below:

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
    development: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.APP_URL_DOCKER,
        dialect: 'postgres'
    },
    test: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.APP_URL_DOCKER,
        dialect: 'postgres'
    },
    production: {
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        host: process.env.APP_URL_DOCKER,
        dialect: 'postgres'
    }
};
```

You can specify the service name of your `postgres database` in your `.env`file. And it should be good for you.

```
// .env file
APP_URL_LOCAL=127.0.0.1
APP_URL_DOCKER=db # database service name
APP_PORT=8000
APP_KEY=6dd63668dab9a309c7c59a2982126a43b064816925a40b9680d16e2665f41b676a87dae4d506712e6332479c82827993059ddefb607b65caa3534b66b20253ed

DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=db_password
DB_NAME=db_name
DB_PORT_CONTAINER=5432
DB_PORT_LOCAL=5433
```